# Python object allocation address

Tags: python, python-2.7, object, memory, allocation

So I encountered an interesting behaviour in Python 2.7, and I an curious to know why is it happening. I defined the following 4 data structures in python 2.7:

- A **set** as '**st**'
- A **list** '**lst**'
- A **tuple** '**tpl**'
- A **dictionary** as '**dct**'

Creating them in python:

```
st = set(['apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'pear', 'orange', 'banana']) 
lst = [1, 2, 3, "4"] 
tpl = (1, 2, 3, '4') 
dct = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3};
```

Here is the representation of the 4 objects:

```
st.__repr__
<method-wrapper '__repr__' of set object at 0x7f234997ba48>

tpl.__repr__
<method-wrapper '__repr__' of tuple object at 0x7f23499667e0>

lst.__repr__
<method-wrapper '__repr__' of list object at 0x7f2349910b48>

dct.__repr__
<method-wrapper '__repr__' of dict object at 0x25af3a0>
```

As you can see, my dictionary was placed in a completely different memory section (0x25af3a0) compared to others (0x7f23499*****).

**My question is, why is the dictionary object got placed to a completely different section of memory?**

Python version is 2.7.3 (compiled with GCC 4.7.2 on linux), linux version is 3.18.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.18.6-1~kali2 (2015-03-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux).

Comment: is that a problem??
is there anything that you need to do with the address?? just a query!!

Comment: No problem, I just want to know why it's happening. Yes I [tried it again](http://pastebin.com/2zvR3W3D) and  dictionary got placed to a different place again.

Comment: Address space layout randomization in action?

Comment: Nitpick: `st.__repr__` is not the representation of the object, it is the representation of the `__repr__` method of the object.

Comment: @tynn Isn't ASLR specific to process memory allocation, and not variable allocation? And why would it only trigger for my dictionary object?

Comment: @DominikAntal no worries. The `repr` of `st` would be `repr(st)` (or `st.__repr__()`, which would show `set(['orange', 'pear', 'apple', 'banana'])`. As it happens, that doesn't show you the memory address, so your mistake was actually a useful one!

Comment: @DominikAntal It was only a guess since Python manages different address blocks. In another context I observed a similar behaviour. But in this case I couldn't,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python uses *a lot* of tiny and temporary objects (especially `dict`s, for passing arguments, storing attributes, etc). To reduce the overhead of allocating and freeing memory every time such an object is created or destroyed, CPython optimizes by pre-allocating arrays of memory slots for various size of small object.

So when you create a small object, Python doesn't allocate memory the way you would expect. Instead uses its own heuristics to select one of the memory locations it has already set aside. New memory is only allocated when the relevant section of Python's "arena" of pre-allocated small blocks is full.